Could not read from remote repository (Ruby on Rails)
I used to deploy code from Github to AWS via Github Actions without any issue. But now, the same code suddenly stopped working. its giving Could not read from remote repository error. I'm still trying to find out its reason.
I'm using following gems.

gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano',                 '~> 3.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails-console', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'capistrano-yarn'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem "sshkit", "1.18.2"
gem 'rails', '5.1.6.2'
https://github.com/miloserdow/capistrano-deploy/tree/v2.2

Github Actions Code: please note that this same code was working perfectly fine.
name:  Deployment
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  deploy_to_xyz:
    name: Deploy to xyz
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      CAP_BRANCH: zzz
      AWS_KEY_ID: xxxx
      AWS_SECRET_KEY:  xxxx
      AWS_REGION:  xxxx
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.5.9
        bundler-cache: true
    - uses: miloserdow/capistrano-deploy@v2.2
      with:
        target: staging
        enc_rsa_key_pth: "xxxx"
        deploy_key:  xxxx
    - name: Success
      # code related to  failure
    - name: Fail deploy notification
      # code related to  failure

it is giving following error:
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 user@xxxxxIp.345s
    ✔ 01 user@xxxxxip 1.349s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-xxxxx-runner.sh 100.0%
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-xxxxx-runner.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-xxxxx-runner.sh
    ✔ 02 user@xxxxxxIP 0.342s
    ✔ 02 user@xxxxxxIP 0.342s
00:02 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git HEAD
      01 ERROR: Repository not found.
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
#<Thread:0x000055aecb8f72b0@/home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in  rescue in block (2 levels) in execute : Exception while executing on host ip: git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
    from /home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in  block (2 levels) in execute 
      01 ERROR: Repository not found.
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
#<Thread:0x000055aecb8f7738@/home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in  rescue in block (2 levels) in execute : Exception while executing on host ip: git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
    from /home/runner/work/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in  block (2 levels) in execute 
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host ip: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host ip: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
 INFO [8a54f66e] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git HEAD on ip
 DEBUG [40ed32b1]   ERROR: Repository not found.
 DEBUG [40ed32b1]   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
 DEBUG [5dd77983]   ERROR: Repository not found.
 DEBUG [5dd77983]   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Error: The process /opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.5.9/x64/bin/bundle failed with exit code 1

it looks it connects to the remote server from github actions, but it fails to get the latest changes from github.
Any idea, what could be the reason of this error ?

Sounds like a permissions issue

@dbugger where and how i can check these permissions

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25240

@dbugger unfortunately this didnt work for me

I had the same issue when I remove Deploy key from repository from GitHub.
Another option can be restricted access to git
you can check it with ssh -T git@github.com from your server
